# how to identify partial template specilization

Tags: c++, templates

I am studying templates where I find this example :

```
template <typename T, int size>
void print(StaticArray<T, size> &array)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < size; ++count)
        std::cout << array[count] << ' ';
}


template <int size>
void print(StaticArray<char, size> &array)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < size; ++count)
        std::cout << array[count];
}
```

Why second `print` function works even though it is having `non-type` parameter `size` and why it is full template specialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not specialization, but [function template overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading), which take different template parameters.

As you said, the 2nd overload still has a template parameter, so it's not a full specialization. And [partial specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) is not allowed for function template; it only works with class templates.